# How to remove default CSS which is appended by sitefinity or any other CMS?

Tags: css, sitefinity

I'm using sitefinity cms and when i add new page, it automatically add its own css to page. how can I remove that?
Also, they doesn't have any id of css.
Here's the css:

link href="/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?compress=0&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bTelerik.Sitefinity.Resources%2c+Version%3d5.1.3210.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3dnull%3aen%3add8ca2b1-dad9-4399-a262-656b242439a7%3ad271177c%3adff30785" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: is it appended internally using style attribute?

Comment: See this thread. http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/designing-styling/heow-to-remove-css-styling-of-built-in-widgets-entirely-and-use-my-own

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the upmark was being it is correct:

See

http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/designing-styling/heow-to-remove-css-styling-of-built-in-widgets-entirely-and-use-my-own

this might also help.

http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/designing-styling/how-to-remove-a-responsive-layout-css-file-

I would strongly urge you to mark it on Sitefinity as something to change.